# sending dataset from AWS S3 to AWS rds PostgreSQL database through AWS Glue

Tags: pyspark, amazon-rds, aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

How to send data from the S3 bucket to the rds PostgreSQL database through AWS glue? Explain each step of setting up the glue studio, performing the glue job and making connections in glue with the rds database.

I have stored my data(CSV file) in an S3 bucket and also created the RDS database, also connected it with the DBeaver.
In glue, I have created the crawler and made the connections with rds. Now, I am stuck at the glue job, getting errors in my script. I expect help in the Glue job and to find where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you share what errors are you getting ?